# Unable to run a bundle built using the 'mkbundle' command

Tags: linux, mono

I am able to build a bundle using the `mkbundle` command. After that when I try to run the application in another Linux system where Mono is not installed, the application is not executed and there are no errors.

Comment: Run `ldd yourmonoapp` on the first machine to understand which libraries are required

Comment: thanks for ur reply and i got this when i run ldd Spectroscopy linux-izpa:~/sp/Spectroscopy/bin/Debug # ldd Spectroscopy
        linux-gate.so.1 (0xb76f0000)
        libmono-2.0.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmono-2.0.so.1 (0xb7399000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xb736d000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xb7364000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xb735f000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7343000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb719d000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76f1000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb717f000)

Comment: So your other target system needs `/usr/lib/libmono-2.0-.20.so.1`

Comment: but i think when i use the mkbundle command the mono library is also embedded into the bundle

Comment: No, it isn't, because of licensing restrictions. This would force you to distribute your application as GPL, so it's optional. Class libraries, on the other hand, are MIT licensed.

Comment: please can you tell me how to do that, i.e., command

Comment: anyone please tell the procedure to make my application run by building all required libraries

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: gdiplus.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor (-) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace --

Comment: at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal (IntPtr hdc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay (IntPtr display_handle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: at System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Spectroscopy.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mkbundle alone will build a binary that **still** has some dependencies on mono libraries.

If you want to be able to 'just drop your app on any recent Linux box and start it' you should do a static build with **mkbundle --static**